# What is the right way to assign 0xFFFFFFFF to an unsigned integer variable?

Tags: c++

If I compile following code

```
size_t a = -1;
```

with MSVC with W4 option I get

```
warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'size_t', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

and I am not 100% sure that `-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF` on all the platforms. Is `-1` bit representation defined by the standard?

Other options are:

```
size_t a = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

size_t a = static_cast<size_t>(-1);
```

Are there some other alternatives?

It can be `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc...

And in the code above I do not know what is the actual size of `size_t`, it can be 4 bit or 8 bit, for example.

Comment: `size_t(-1)` is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF on platforms where `size_t` is 64 bits large. Unsigned integral types are required to perform arithmetic modulo `2^n` where `n` is the number of bits in the type's representation. So which number do you want to assign - 0xFFFFFFFF specifically, or the largest representable value?

Comment: [~decltype(a)()](https://godbolt.org/z/Yvj9M9h6K) if you really want all bits on, instead of assuming twos complement.  a.k.a `~size_t{}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is `-1` bit representation defined by the standard?

Comment: @paddy `-1` when set to an unsigned variable will be `0xFF...FF` no matter what representation signed integers use. So the `= -1` works regardless if 2s complement is used or not.

Comment: Even shorter to write is `size_t x = size_t(-1);`, here compiler doesn't guess any bit-representation of `-1`, it just follows standard rules of conversion of signed integers to unsigned. Compiler just sign-extends signed integer to make it of same bit-length as destination unsigned integer and then just raw-copies over to unsigned. In asm and in CPU unsigned and signed are same value, in CPU everything is unsigned, signeds are just represented in bit-complement form. Non-optimized asm sequence could look like `mov edx, -1; movsx rax, edx`, here `movsx` just sign-extends 32-bit `-1` to 64 bit

Comment: Probably yes, by more recent versions. I don't remember the details off the top. I don't see how this question is relevant to the issue at hand though. You aren't using any bitwise operations here, so why do you care about bit representation?

Comment: @Arty `size_t(-1)` is a good idea it is shorter than `static_cast<size_t>(-1)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes it is modulo operations not bitwise.

Comment: Do you want to assign the maximum value of the type, or do you specifically want to assign `0xFFFFFFFF`?

Comment: @KeithThompson maximum value (my understanding is that it is the same)

Comment: It's the same only if `size_t` happens to be 32 bits.

Comment: @KeithThompson Did you mean that `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() != 0xFFFFFFFF` ?

Comment: That's true, but it's not what I meant. `size_t` and `uint64_t` are different types. The maximum value of `uint64_t` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. The maximum value of `size_t` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size_t a = -1;`

This will initialize `a` with the biggest value `size_t` can hold. This is defined in terms of modulo arithmetics and not bit patterns. So this is true regardless if signed integers use 2s complement or something else.

Unsigned integers are required to be encoded directly as their binary representation so the largest value will always have the `0xFF...FF` bit pattern.

To silence the cast both of your solution work. It's just a matter of personal taste which one you use.

Answer (score 4):

To set all bits and silence the warning, without a cast, for all *unsigned* types:

```
a = 1;
a = -a;
```

or

```
a = 0;
a = ~a;
```

If you need a const or constexpr value (and really don't want to use casts):

```
constexpr size_t a = [] { size_t a = 0; return ~a; }();
```

Comment: I don't see how. The closest I can think of is `constexpr size_t a = [] { decltype(a) x = 0; return ~x; }();` if that is what you mean

Comment: @bolov Yes, I suspect that works for a one-line assignment too:  `a = [] { decltype(a) x = 0; return ~x; }();` for any _unsigned_ type.

Comment: if you already have a value and want to change it you can do `[&] { a = 0; a = ~a; }();` or `a = [=] { a = 0; return ~a; }();`

Comment: @bolov Now I'm thinking  `a = a&0 - 1;`.  Hmm likely runs afoul if `a` is indefinite.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: `a = [] { decltype(a) x = 0; return ~x; }(); ` this won't work, you need to explicitly capture `a` (for the `decltype(a)` inside the lambda). `a` is implicitly captured only if it's constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

> Is -1 bit representation defined by the standard?

The signed bit representation doesn't matter. What matters is how the conversion from signed to unsigned is specified in the standard.

The result of converting -1 to an unsigned integer always result in largest representable value of the unsigned type. It's safe to assume that the bit representation of largest representable unsigned integer is all ones.

An assumption that isn't portable to all systems is that `std::size_t` is 64 bits wide. It's entirely feasible that `a == 0xFFFF` on another system.

Comment: Does the standard define what is `size_t a = -2;` ?

Comment: @Dmitriano Yes. All conversions from integer to unsigned are defined. Furthermore, since C++20 all conversions between integers are defined, signed included.